# When i've to use json format in postgresql?

Tags: json, database, postgresql, performance, graphql

Now I'm working with GraphQL and postgresql as the database.

As you know, we can easily map data to schemas with GraphQL.

If I just use a simple join table query, we need to process the data to fit the output like graphql schema, but if I do the query using json format, the query will be very hard to read.

My question is, when should we use json format, and when should we do a simple table join? Is there any particular concern if we use json format or simple join table? and how does the performance compare between the two?

Comment: postgres is a relational database so you should prefer by default to join tables, especially when you have one-to-many or many-to-many relationships. Then jsonb may be an interesting no-sql solution for storing structured data in some specific use cases, but the performances will usually be lower and with some limitations regarding the updates. Then your question refers to the database design which relies on experience & expertise.

Comment: if you are using graphql only for the purpose of reducing dataset & nothing else.. then I would recommend you to checkout - https://github.com/restmap/restmap-node